# Generating a manifest.mf file in META-INF

Tags: java, maven, datanucleus, isis

I want to persist a class to an RDMS datastore and I created custom mapping.
In the [datanucleus documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/extensions/rdbms_java_types.html), it mentioned.

> *The only thing we need to do is enable use of this Java type when running DataNucleus. To do this we create a plugin.xml (at the root of
>   our CLASSPATH) to contain our mappings.*

I added `plugin.xml`  in `src/main/resources` of my `webapp` module.
It also stated that,

> Note that we also require a MANIFEST.MF file as per the Extensions
>   Guide.

But I cannot generate META-INF and manifest.mf even if I've added this in my `pom.xml` (*of webapp module*):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
    ...
    </plugin>
```

Can someone enlighten me? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `maven-jar-plugin` will generate a `MANIFEST.MF` by default. Remove your current configuration, post your POM, and post the result you are having.

Comment: oh sorry, i totally missed where the location it generated. i've just found it